# How can I randomize the values within my numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
[[ 208.47   26.  ]
 [ 202.84   17.  ]
 [ 143.37   10.  ]
 ..., 
 [  45.99    3.  ]
 [ 159.31   10.  ]
 [  34.12    4.  ]]
[[ 58.64   1.  ]
 [ 44.31  19.  ]
 [ 37.89  14.  ]
 ..., 
 [ 46.86   4.  ]
 [ 60.73   5.  ]
 [ 41.91   6.  ]]
[[  36.6     4.  ]
 [ 219.29   17.  ]
 [  64.77    5.  ]
 ..., 
 [  51.85   37.  ]
 [ 161.26   10.  ]
 [  53.63   20.  ]]
[[  52.97   32.  ]
 [  51.32    3.  ]
 [ 196.23    4.  ]
 ..., 
 [  41.39    8.  ]
 [  47.49    5.  ]
 [  34.34    3.  ]]
```

I have this `numpy` array entering my function:

```
def initialize_centroids(points, k):
    """returns k centroids from the initial points"""
    centroids = points.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(centroids)
    print centroids
    return centroids[:k]
```

Now what the function is currently doing is, shuffling the values and sending the first k of them. I want to basically randomize the values of the first column between 0 and 300 and the second between 0 and 100. How would I do this?

This is part of my work on building a K-Means algorithm using Python.

Comment: You want `np.random.rand(k, 2) * [300, 100]`?

Comment: Can you please tell me how the output would look like @kazemakase

Comment: It would look awful in a SO comment. Why don't you try to run it in a Python interpreter?

Comment: Yes! That works! put that down as an answer and I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kazemakase has commented, the answer is simply using:

```
np.random.rand(k, 2) * [300, 100]
```